# How to design a Gaussian Process which respects input order symmetry

Tags: gaussian-process, symmetry

I am trying to design a Gaussian Process model for optimizing experimental parameters. In particular, an experiment requires *n* parameterizations of points on the 2D Cartesian plane. For a particular set of points, I can assign a score indicating the fitness for that set of points. The Gaussian Process takes as input the points {(x_i, y_i) for i=0...n} as [x_0, x_1, ... x_n, y_0, y_1, ... y_n]. Importantly, the fitness score does not depend on the ordering of the points, so that

f([x_0, x_1, ... x_n, y_0, y_1, ... y_n]) = f([x_n, x_0, ... x_1, y_n, y_0, ... y_1]).

How can I design my GP to respect this symmetry?

Comment: If we can find a measure of distance between input points that is permutation invariant and relevant to your problem, then you can use that distance measure in your kernel function and be good to go. Are you familiar with any by any chance?

Comment: I am familiar, however I am unsure how to design an appropriate permutationally invariant distance function since the underlying points are Euclidean. I started with a 1D case, and based on these slides (http://gpss.cc/gpss19/slides/STMarkWorkshop2019.pdf) I was able to create a permutationally invariant GP by sorting the input data by x location, but that is no longer possible with 2D data. As I understand it, it seems to be a problem of kernel design, but I'm not sure how to go about it. The other issue is that the orbit of the permutations is n!, so I can't exactly use the additive method.